# PageIndexChanging problems

Tags: c#, html, gridview

The GridView 'Sqldata' fired event `PageIndexChanging` which wasn't handled.
How to handle it?

```
protected void Sqldata_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {
      Sqldata.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      Sqldata.DataBind();
  }
```

and

```
<-asp:GridView  ID="Sqldata" runat="server" autoGenerateColumns ="False" ShowFooter ="True" showHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="Dado Não Encontrado" AllowPaging="True"              
              Width="1100px" Height="350px" CssClass="auto-style5" Font-Names="Arial" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="20">
```

***Full Code***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.ComponentModel;



namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class Lis_Mov_Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //Connection String,  criada pelo web form Configuração. (Caminho do servidor. EX: Data Source = Nome/SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = table; user Id = sa; password = 1234) 
        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Session["Nome"].ToString() == "SuperAdministrador") //Para poder usar o super-administrador criado em código...
                {
                    Label2.Text = Session["Nome"].ToString();
                }
                else if (Session["Nome"] != null && Session["Funcao"].ToString() == "1")// Evitar que o utilizador navegue via URL e verificando se o nome está vazio ou funcao diferente da do site
                {
                    Label2.Text = Session["Nome"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
                    Label2.Text = Session["Nome"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");//Se o utilizador arrancar com esta página é rederecionado para a página login (ou então dava erro)
            }
            if (!IsPostBack)//Verifica se a página foi carregada a primeria vez ou não
            {
                populateGridView();//Variavél Criada do tipo void
            }
        }
         public void populateGridView()
        {
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  * FROM Movimentos", sqlCon);//Mostra os dados inseridos na tabela referida
                sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            }
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Sqldata.DataSource = dtbl;
                Sqldata.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
                Sqldata.DataSource = dtbl;
                Sqldata.DataBind();
                Sqldata.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                Sqldata.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                Sqldata.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dtbl.Columns.Count;
                Sqldata.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "Não foi encontrado dados...";
                Sqldata.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            }
        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Lis_Mov_Admin.aspx"); //Mostrar tudo
        }


        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Pesquisa os dados da tabela usando textbox

            string filter = "";
            string command = "SELECT * FROM Movimentos WHERE";


            if (textDataMovimento.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + "[Data Movimento] LIKE '%" + textDataMovimento.Text + "%' AND";
            }
            if (textDataValor.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Data Valor] LIKE '%" + textDataValor.Text + "%' AND";
            }
            if (textDescricao.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Descricao] LIKE '%" + textDescricao.Text + "%' AND";
            }
            if (textValor.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Valor] LIKE '%" + textValor.Text + "%' AND";
            }
            if (textTipodeMovimento.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Tipo de Movimento] LIKE '%" + textTipodeMovimento.Text + "%'AND";
            }
            if (filter.Length > 0)
            {
                Sqldata.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
                string FinalFilter = filter.Remove(filter.Length - 3);
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = command + FinalFilter;
                Sqldata.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Sqldata.DataBind();
            }
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
        {
            //confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the
            //specified ASP.NET server control at run time.
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=register.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "applicantion/excel";
            StringWriter ad = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter sd = new HtmlTextWriter(ad);
            Sqldata.RenderControl(sd);
            Response.Write(ad.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
        protected void myButton_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Imp_Mov_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void myButton_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Imp_Doc_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void myButton_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Lis_Mov_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void myButton_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Lis_Doc_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void myButton_6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Dados_Sinc_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void myButton_5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Dados_Nao_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void myButton_7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Criar_Contas_Admin.aspx");
        }
        protected void mybutton_8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["Nome"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        protected void Sqldata_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Sqldata.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Sqldata.DataSource= sqlCon ;
            Sqldata.DataBind();
            DataBind();

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used webforms but don't you need to set onpageindexchanging="Sqldata_PageIndexChanging"? You presumably also need to get the DataSource before doing DataBinding.

Comment: @sr28 the thingo is my DataSource is assuming as an error and i don't know why , and paging is doing fine now but rest of database data is not loading after paging.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It appears underlined in code by red

Comment: Can you show the line of code that is showing as underlined in red?

Comment: Sqldata.DataSource=MyVariable;

Comment: The assumption here is that Sqldata is your Gridview and therefore has a DataSource. When you hover over the red line what error do you see?

Comment: Yes it says that myvariable is not in the context , how do i put it on?

Comment: Or what do i need to put after datasource=""??

Comment: Well presumably it will be the same datasource you have in the first place to bind to the gridview. So, if you have a method like GetData() or something, which returns a dataset or some other suitable data source you would use that. It's just rebinding to the current data set already in use

Comment: Can i put here the code ? i'm using the same dataset and shows the error

Comment: Yes, please add the code, but in the question, not as an answer

Comment: So what's the mistake there ?

Comment: I would be tempted to refactor this and split the bit that returns the data (the data table) into a separate method. Then call that method from within populate data grid. You can then call that from the Sqldata_PageIndexChanging method for the DataSource

Comment: Basically, you're DataSource looks like it should be the data returned in your DataTable that's in the populateGridView method, but that's a void and does the binding at that point. You need to split this out. Alternatively, if this doesn't ever change then store it in a global variable and just reference it where you need it

Comment: Thank you , i appreciate your attention . For many guys like you in this community . Your explanations helped me a lot .

Comment: No problem. If this works for you I'll pop it as the answer and you can mark it as correct so others can benefit from this

Comment: Did my answer below work for you? If so, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments I'll put the steps here to summarize:

In the html you need to ensure 'onpageindexchanging' is referencing your method like this onpageindexchanging="Sqldata_PageIndexChanging".

In your 'Sqldata_PageIndexChanging' method you need to ensure your data is being rebound to the gridview. Looking at your code you initially populate the data grid using 'populateGridView' method. Assuming the data bound to the gridview in this method is the data source you need you should split the part of this that gets the data and puts it into your datatable out, so it can be referenced elsewhere. Alternatively, if the data doesn't change you can store it into a global variable and reference it where you need it. Ultimately, in your 'Sqldata_PageIndexChanging' method you need to set the DataSource like this:

```
protected void Sqldata_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
 {
    Sqldata.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    Sqldata.DataSource= //your data source whether from global variable or new method;
    Sqldata.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need to do a small change in **Sqldata_PageIndexChanging**

Remove the following two lines

`Sqldata.DataSource= sqlCon ;
 Sqldata.DataBind();`

and add `populateGridView` method below to `Sqldata.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;`